# How do I properly add third party class library to laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add this closure table class to laravel
https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable
I followed the  install instructions
I added the folder to my vendor/Franzose folder and updated config/app.php

```
'Franzose\ClosureTable\ClosureTableServiceProvider',
```

and in my composer.json file

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*"
    "franzose/closure-table": "4.*"
},
```

but get the general class not found error
FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 6528: Class 'Franzose\ClosureTable\ClosureTableServiceProvider' not found

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the comma and ran it again and                            wraycode@ubuserve:~/dev/location-store$ composer dump-autoload
Generating autoload files then pushed those up but still got the not foud

Comment: do I need to add path in autoload_psr4.php?

Comment: I tried adding this linie in the array  of autoload_psr4.php                                   'Franzone\\' => array($vendorDir . '/franzone/Franzone/ClosureTable'), and moved to Franzone class to a folder /vendor/franzone/Franzone/ still getting same error

Comment: Did the `composer install` run without errors when you initially installed the package?

Comment: looks like that work I was able to successfully us the class with artisian

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already have solved the above question. But here's one tip that will avoid some trouble later on.

Whenever you just want to install a package, without changing or updating other dependencies, do the following:

```
composer require <package-name>
```

In your case

```
composer require franzose/closure-table
```

You do not need to manually add the name of the package in the composer.json file or add the package folder to the vendor folder.  The require command does it for you.

Here is the downside of running composer update. From the documentation, composer update does the following:

> In order to get the latest versions of the dependencies and to update the composer.lock file, you should use the update command.

What this means is that, composer update will update all the dependencies to their recent versions. But if your code has a tight dependency on an older version of a particular package, then your code will break after you run update command. This has happened to me with many packages which I use from GitHub. You do not realize the problem, till the code starts breaking.

Hence, you should run composer update only when you are sure that updating  the versions wouldn't affect the code.

Hope this helps!